# Shortcut to move windows between Mission Control spaces?

Tags: keyboard, windows, mission-control

I can switch to another desktop by pressing CTRL-RIGHT or CTRL-LEFT. Can I also somehow take the active window with me to the new active desktop (similar to Ubuntu/Unity)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Options provided by OSX

1. Using your mouse, click and hold the window you want to move to another Space.
2. **a)** While still holding your mouse button down, use your Spaces keyboard shortcut to move to the desired Space. (default: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>)

   **b)** Drag the window to the edge of the screen. Wait a second or two and the window will be dragged into the next space.

   You can change the delay before the OS switches spaces using...(here 2 seconds)

   ```
    defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 2.0; killall Dock;
   ```

### Third-party solutions

- **[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)** (unlimited free trial available)

Your question has been asked before on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706987/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcut-for-moving-active-window-to-another-screen).

Comment: This is a good answer - but it sucks that there's no way to do this without installing apps.